# Slycot Import Error: DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, importerror

I have installed Slycot successfully on other windows machines, but I am running into an error I have not seen before while attempting to install it on my work desktop.  My usual procedure is as follows:

1. Install PythonXY
2. Download Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 and SP1 using link from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
3. Download and install Slycot from binary provided in http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

This has worked before, and it appeared to install with no issues, but I get the following error when I try to import slycot:

```
>>> import slycot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slycot\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from slycot.analysis import ab01nd,ab05md,ab05nd,ab07nd,ab08nd, ab09ad
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slycot\analysis.py", line 21, in <module>
    from slycot import _wrapper
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I went to the location of the source in thhe site-packages directory and indeed the _wrapper.pyd file is there.  Any ideas why it can't find the DLL?

Comment: Numpy comes with PythonXY.  Installing the numpy-MKL from that sites breaks numpy on my install.  I get:

RuntimeError:  module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed PythonXY and followed my original procedure and the installation worked the second time around.  I'm chocking it up to humidity issues (-;